# idle timeout for android app activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timeout

I am writing an Android app (ICS) for a tablet. The user moves from Activity A to Activity B to Activity C with the touch of a button. I want to return from Activity C to Activity A after 10 seconds. Is there some way to count to 10 without locking up Activity C?

I've succeeded with an asyncTask but if I startActivity(A) in the onPostExecute() it feels like I'm violating the guideline that an asyncTask should not mess with the UI. I've tried get() but that does lock up Activity C while it's waiting for the 10 seconds to pass.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the usage of a AsyncTask instead of a Timer?

Comment: Why use `Timer`? Android's event system (see Handler) allows for more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have any `View` instance in your activity, you can use [View.postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to post runnable with a given delay. In this runnable you can call [Activity.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29). You should also use [View.removeCallbacks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to remove your callback in `onDestroy()`, to avoid your callback being called after user already navigated back from your activity.

Using `AsyncTask` just to count some time is just an overkill (unless you want to use `AsyncTask` to actually do some useful, background work). The `Looper` and `Handler` classes provide everything you need to execute any code on UI thread after a given delay. The `View` methods mentioned above are just convenience methods exposing the `Handler` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using AsyncTask works fine as you describe. From Android Documentation:

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.

Since it is invoked on UI thread you should be fine.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a alarm manager for that. Set it to send a broadcast 10 seconds starting from activity a and implement a base activity for activity a b and c to receive the broadcast, after receiving the broadcast just end the current activity and start activity a with a new flag. If the current instance is activity a then ignore if not start activity a. Something like that.

As for the idle part you can update the alarm manager on every action, upon entering activity etc.

The advantage of this implementation is that you dont have to go through the hassle of having to worry about context leaks, persisting timers across activities and such. and can make use of what is already there. You can also consider using a service though.

If not you can just use the shared preference store the time to time out and check or update against it for the actions.. A simpler implementation.

Good luck.